# Reference Map of EUROCONTROL charging zones

Tags: navigation

I'm building out an application to calculate EUROCONTROL navigation fees. EUROCONTROL make one of these already, but I need to replicate the functionality within my own stack.

In the aforementioned EUROCONTROL app, there is a data file containing what appears data in a geospatial format. In order to do the required calculations, I first need to understand that data format.

My first impression is the first row is some metadata. EG means the UK. From there the number pairs begin and end the same, indicating a closed polygon.

Example for EG (so UK) is here

```
3274 -600
3300 -600
3360 -600
3420 -600
3480 -600
3540 -600
3600 -600
3660 -600
3660 -540
3660 -484
3660 -480
3660 -420
3660 -390
3660 -360
3660 -300
3660 -275
3660 -240
3660 -180
3660 -120
3660 -111
3660 -60
3655 0
3600 0
3420 300
3300 300
3090 120
3067 120
3060 88
3040 88
3000 -15
3000 -120
2930 -480
2940 -480
2970 -480
3000 -480
3060 -480
3140 -330
3235 -330
3265 -490
3320 -415
3325 -440
3320 -495
3285 -540
3274 -600
```

Plotting the numbers in an SVG, so simply turning the numbers into pixels gets me this...
[image]

I'm hoping that matches a EUROCONTROL map someplace. Geospatial data  can be quite complex, and I don't really understand a lot of that complexity, so projection might be off (or any number of other things).

Can anyone point me in the direction of this within an official EUROCONTROL document? From there its a short hop to understanding how that original data file can be translated into some GIS software that gets me to the next stage of my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the map of the European airspace, however you have mirrored it such that north is now south and vice versa.

[image]
<sub>source: Eurocontrol</sub>

- GC    Spain Canarias
- AZ    Portugal (Azores)
- LP    Portugal Lisbo
- LE    Spain Continent.
- LF    France
- LS    Switzerland
- LI    Italy
- LM    Malta
- LG    Greece
- LC    Cyprus
- LT    Turkey
- UD    Armenia
- UG    Georgia
- LB    Bulgaria
- LA    Albania
- LW    Republic of North Macedonia
- LY    Serb.-Montenegro
- LD    Croatia
- LQ    Bosnia Herzeg.
- LJ    Slovenia
- LO    Austria
- LH    Hungary
- LR    Romania
- LU    Moldova
- EP    Poland
- EG    United Kingdom
- ED    Germany
- EH    Netherlands
- EB    Belg.-Luxembourg
- ES    Sweden
- EK    Denmark
- EF    Finland
- LZ    Slovak Republic
- LK    Czech Republic
- EY    Lithuania
- EN    Norway
- EI    Ireland
- EV    Latvia